# How can I display the result of the child component in the parent component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

my application consists of a filter select by provinces, the filter is a modal that shows me the result in the filter component (child), I would like to show the result in the parent not in the filter modal. I do not know what to pass to the parent to show the result or how to show it on the screen.

///parent component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getClinic } from '../../api/drupalAPI'
import {Clinic} from '@icofcv/common';
import { selectClinics } from '../../actions/detailClinics'
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import contentUtils from '../../lib/contentUtils'
import { SearchFilterClinics } from './SearchFilterClinics'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';


    const ClinicList = () => {

    const [clinicList, setClinicList] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);
    const [clinicListFiltered, setClinicListFiltered] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);
    const [searchClinic, setSearchClinic] = useState("");
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const navigate = useNavigate(); 
    ///modal control

    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    const openModal = () => setIsOpen(true);
    const closeModal = () => setIsOpen(false);
    
    console.log(searchClinic);
    
    const fetchClinicList = async () => {
        getClinic().then((response)=>{
            console.log(response)
            setClinicList(response);
            setClinicListFiltered(response)
        }).catch ( (error)  => {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        });
    }

    const handleChange=e=>{
        setSearchClinic(e.target.value);
        filter(e.target.value);
      }
      
      const filter=(termSearch)=>{
        const resultSearch= clinicList.filter((element)=>{
          if(element.title.toString().toLowerCase().includes(termSearch.toLowerCase())
          ){
            return element;
          }
        });
        setClinicListFiltered(resultSearch);
      }

      function handleAddToDetail(clinic) {
        dispatch(selectClinics(clinic));
        navigate('clinicdetail');
      }

      function goToPageSearchFilterClinics() {
        navigate('filterclinics');
    } 
  

    useEffect (() => {
        fetchClinicList();  
    }, []);

    return(
            <>
                <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                    <div style={{width:'5rem'}}>
                        {/* <button  onClick={() => goToPageSearchFilterClinics()}>filtro</button>  */}
                        <button  onClick={openModal}>filtro</button>  
                    </div>
                    < SearchFilterClinics  isOpen={isOpen} closeModal={closeModal} clinicFilter={clinicFilter}></SearchFilterClinics>

                    <Form className="d-flex">
                        <Form.Control
                        type="search"
                        value={searchClinic}
                        placeholder="Search"
                        className="me-2"
                        aria-label="Search"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                    </Form>
                    
              </div>
                <div className="content-cliniclist">
                    
                    {
                         clinicListFiltered.map((clinic) => (
                             <div style={{marginBottom: '3rem'}}>
                                <button
                                    type="button"
                                    onClick={() => handleAddToDetail(clinic)}
                                    style={{all: 'unset'}}
                                    >
                                    
                                    <div>
                                        {/* <img src={ contentUtils.getLargeImageUrl(clinic.logoWidth )} alt="#"></img> */}
                                        <div>{clinic.title}</div>
                                        <div>{clinic.propsPhone}</div>
                                        <div>{clinic.mobile}</div>
                                        <div>{clinic.email}</div>
                                        <div>{clinic.registry}</div>
                                    </div>
                                </button>
                             </div>
                        ))
                    }
                                
             </div>
            </>  
    )
}

 export default ClinicList; 


////child component

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Select, { SingleValue } from 'react-select'
import { getClinic } from '../../api/drupalAPI'
import {Clinic} from '@icofcv/common';
import "./Modal.css";

interface Props {
    isOpen: boolean,
    clinicFilter: String,
    closeModal: () => void
}


export const SearchFilterClinics : React.FC<Props> = ({ children, isOpen, closeModal, clinicFilter }) => {

         ////filter

         type OptionType = {
            value: string;
            label: string;
          };
    
          
            const provincesList: OptionType[] = [
                { value: 'Todos', label: 'Todos' },
                { value: 'Valencia', label: 'Valencia' },
                { value: 'Castellon', label: 'Castellon' },
                { value: 'Alicante', label: 'Alicante' },
               
            ]

    const [clinicList, setClinicList] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);
    const [clinicListFilteredSelect, setClinicListFilteredSelect] = useState<Clinic[]>([]);
    const [filterSelectClinic, setFilterSelectClinic] = useState<SingleValue<OptionType>>(provincesList[0]);

    const handleChangeSelect = async (provinceList: SingleValue<OptionType>) => {
        getClinic().then((response) => {
            setClinicList(response);
            setClinicListFilteredSelect(response)
            setFilterSelectClinic(provinceList);
            filterSelect(provinceList );
          }).catch ((error) => {
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        });         
      }

       
      const filterSelect=(termSearch)=>{
        const resultFilterSelect = clinicList.filter((element) => {
          if(element.province?.toString().toLowerCase().includes(termSearch.value.toLowerCase() )
        
          ){
            return element;
          }
        });
        setClinicListFilteredSelect(resultFilterSelect);
      }

      const handleModalContainerClick = (e) => e.stopPropagation();

   

    return  (
                <>
                     <div className={`modal ${isOpen && "is-open"}`} onClick={closeModal}>
                         <div className="modal-container" onClick={handleModalContainerClick}>
                            <button className="modal-close" onClick={closeModal}>x</button>
                            {children}
                           
                            <div>
                                <h1>Encuentra tu clínica</h1>
                            </div>
                                 <div>
                                    <form>
                                        
                                        <label>Provincia</label>
                                            <Select 
                                                defaultValue={filterSelectClinic}
                                                options={provincesList}
                                                onChange={handleChangeSelect}
                                                />

                                       </form>


                                { 
                                  
                                    clinicListFilteredSelect.map((clinicFilter) => (
                                        <div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.title}</div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.propsPhone}</div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.mobile}</div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.email}</div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.province} </div>
                                            <div>{clinicFilter.registry}</div>
                                        </div>
                                    ))
                                }
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                          
                </>
            )
}
```

Comment: can u pls create add this code on sandbox or codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to pass a callback function to the parent and set the state value in the parent, not in the child.** ([This is known as lifting state up.](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html))

In your case this would involve moving

```js
const [filterSelectClinic, setFilterSelectClinic] = useState<SingleValue<OptionType>>(provincesList[0]);
```

Into the *parent component*. Then passing the `setFilterSelectClinic` function into the *child component*.

```js
<SearchFilterClinics setFilterSelectClinic={(value) => setFilterSelectClinic(value)} isOpen={isOpen} closeModal={closeModal} clinicFilter={clinicFilter}/>
```

The value (within the parenthesis) is being passed up by the *child component*. This is the value you set here:

```js
getClinic().then((response) => {
 ...
 // this is the function we pass in from the parent. It set's the value
 // of the callback function to provinceList
    setFilterSelectClinic(provinceList);
 ...
```

We then `setFilterSelectClinic` to that value. Meaning `filterSelectClinic` now has the value passed up in the callback.